# Fedora does not load some sites in home network

Tags: networking, fedora

Since I switched from Windows 8.1 to Fedora 20 (my first time Linux experience) I have problems in my home network.

When I surf from the office with the notebook, every site loads fine.
As soon as I get home some sites just do not load or are just extremely slow.

What I tried:
- Ethernet or Wireless
- Tried it with brothers notebook with Windows 8.1(Ethernet and Wireless)

**Any idea what could be wrong with my settings?**

PS: I'm happy to say that `stackexchange.com` loads normally from my home network :D

Comment: Are you connecting through a switch or home router? What if you plug the laptop directly into the network connection and bypass any such device?

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your home internet connection. First do ping , wait for a minute, Ctrl-C and check how many packets lost, what is average latency and was site resolved correctly. After that do traceroute  to see what is the exact cause for the slowness/packet drop. If you see that this is on your provider side - call you provider, if it is between your router and your computer figure out how to fix your local network.